# Mapping mesh's vertices to integer coordinates

Tags: computer-vision, computational-geometry, mesh

## The Situation

I have a mesh (vertices, triangles, vertex normals and vertex colors) whose vertices currently have floating point coordinates (e.g [1.1, 0.8, 2.1]). I am interested in **rounding the vertex coordinates to integers**, i.e. [1.1, 0.8, 2.1] gets mapped to [1, 1, 2]. If I do this, however, I get a many-to-one mapping as also [0.55, 1.4, 1.6] gets mapped to [1, 1, 2].

## The Question

What is the most sensible way to **aggregate** the information (triangles, vertex normals & vertex colors) for all vertices that **map to the same** integer coordinates? As the transformation gives rise to duplicate triangles, I tried to discard those, but I am not content with the result.

Comment: Sounds like an XY question. You should explain why you are rounding those coordinates, which does not sound as a good idea.

Comment: As a means of compression ;)

Comment: You should have very very good reasons to perform such a compression.